# Do I need to keep uploading all files even if I make a small change on NuxtJS

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I am new to NuxtJS and JavaScript frameworks in particular. To host the files on an online server I need to generate static files. Even if I make a small change on one file I have to re-upload all the files again. Is that productive? Normally I can open the server and make changes to one file and upload it. But here I have to upload all files everytime.

Comment: `Is that productive?` What do you mean?

Comment: There has been two votes to close the question as `unclear what you're asking`. I'd suggest you improve your question quality by detailing what server you're using and how does the file upload works.

Comment: My question does not involve any particular web server or file upload process. The doubt I'm having is why do we need to generate static files from NuxtJS and upload them to server everytime we make any change? Why cannot we host the original files we are working on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes.

Some of the reasons why:

1. Your generated files are not supposed to be versioned, so any changes you make there, won't (shouldn't) be committed and pushed to git.
2. If you change the generated files and forget to change the actual code, the next time you generate the files again, those changes will be overwritten.
3. It's not going to be easy at all to make even small changes directly into the generated files.
4. You shouldn't be making changes straight into production. Also, the changes you make there shouldn't be reflected in your localhost, so you're going to have version conflicts pretty soon if you keep doing it like that.

There is, however, a way to make all of that easier. With continuous integration/continuous deployment, you can have it all set up so for every change committed/merged into a specific branch on you version control will be built and automatically pushed to your production server.

It seems to me like you are not familiar with version control (mainly git) nor continuous integration, so here's some topics on the matter:

GIT:

- [Learn git concepts, not commands](https://dev.to/unseenwizzard/learn-git-concepts-not-commands-4gjc)
- [5 Free Courses to Learn Git and Github in Depth](https://dev.to/javinpaul/5-free-courses-to-learn-git-and-github-in-depth-jpp)

Continuous Integration / Continuous Deployment

- [Understanding Continuous Integration](https://dev.to/abulkay/understanding-continuous-integration)
- [Explain Continuous Integration Like Im Five](https://dev.to/snwfdhmp/continuous-integration-like-im-five)